# How to filter with conditions to add to new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to work with dataframe that looks like:

| home | away | home_score | away_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tampa Bay | Colorado | 3 | 1 |
| San Jose | Colombus | 1 | 3 |
| New England | San Jose | 1 | 5 |
| Colorado | Tampa Bay | 2 | 0 |
| New England | KC Wizards | 2 | 1 |

My goal is to compare 'home_score' with 'away_score' and choose the string from 'home' or 'away' to store that value in to separate column based on which score was lower.

For example, for the first row, as away_score is 1 I should be able to add "Colorado" to a separate column.

Desired outcome:

| home | away | home_score | away_score | lost_team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tampa Bay | Colorado | 3 | 1 | Colorado |

I tried to search for the task but I was not successful in finding methods.

Comment: If score are equals?

Comment: if score are equals, both of them should be listed

Comment: Teams separated by a comma?

Comment: Nope, list them both in separate rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.where`

```
df['lost_team'] = np.where(df['home_score'] < df['away_score'], df['home'], df['away'])
print(df)

# Output
          home        away  home_score  away_score    lost_team
0    Tampa Bay    Colorado           3           1     Colorado
1     San Jose    Colombus           1           3     San Jose
2  New England    San Jose           1           5  New England
3     Colorado   Tampa Bay           2           0    Tampa Bay
4  New England  KC Wizards           2           1   KC Wizards
```

If a draw is possible, use `np.select`:

```
conds = [df['home_score'] < df['away_score'],
         df['home_score'] > df['away_score']]
choices = [df['home'], df['away']]
draw = df[['home', 'away']].agg(list, axis=1)

df['lost_team'] = np.select(condlist=conds, choicelist=choices, default=draw).explode()
df = df.explode('lost_team')
print(df)

# Output
          home        away  home_score  away_score    lost_team
0    Tampa Bay    Colorado           3           1     Colorado
1     San Jose    Colombus           1           3     San Jose
2  New England    San Jose           1           5  New England
3     Colorado   Tampa Bay           2           0    Tampa Bay
4  New England  KC Wizards           2           1   KC Wizards
5       Team A      Team B           0           0       Team A  # Row 1
5       Team A      Team B           0           0       Team B  # Row 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` to check the condition on each row and save the result:

```
df['lost_team'] = df.apply(lambda row: 
                           'Equal' if row['home_score'] == row['away_score'] else (
                           row['away'] if row['home_score'] > row['away_score'] else row['home']), 
                           axis=1)
print(df)
```

---

```
          home        away  home_score  away_score    lost_team
0    Tampa Bay    Colorado           3           1     Colorado
1     San Jose    Columbus           1           3     San Jose
2  New England    San Jose           1           5  New England
3     Colorado   Tampa Bay           2           0    Tampa Bay
4  New England  KC Wizards           2           1   KC Wizards
5       Team A      Team B           1           1        Equal
```